# How much time take to reflect PlatformEventSubscriberConfig record in salesforce production

Tags: salesforce, apex, workbench

I used workbench to create PlatformEventSubscriberConfig record using this POST Endpoint: /services/data/v51.0/tooling/sobjects/PlatformEventSubscriberConfig

{
"BatchSize": "2000",
"DeveloperName":"YourNameTriggerConfig",
"MasterLabel":"YourNameTriggerConfig",
"PlatformEventConsumerId": "01qXXXXXXXXX",  <-- Apex Trigger ID
"UserId": "005XXXXXXXXXX"  <-- Desired User ID
}

It dosent reflect in the org. How much time will it take to reflect in the org

Comment: Did you stop and then restart the subscription?